# How do I share data between two Windows PCs via wi-fi?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, wireless-networking, network-shares

I have a broadband connection with a WiFi router. I have installed a new PC at home and it is working well and is able to use the internet. The problem I am facing is to share the data from the old one. The new OS is Windows 7 and the old one is Windows XP. I just want to transfer all my data from the Windows XP machine to the Windows 7 one, so how can i use the WiFi network for this purpose.

Comment: just to point out, connecting the two systems via ethernet is likely to be a LOT faster.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek, you are absolutely right. I was able to share but the speeds were dead slow. The transfer was taking place at no more than 400 KB/sec whereas in ethernet is in higher MBs

Comment: NOTHING is as awesome as point to point gig-e ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all your personal data (My Documents, etc.) on the new machine, then you can enable file sharing on the old XP computer and copy/paste them from the new computer. A description of the steps to take to do this can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304040) (Microsoft Support).

Another option is to map the relevant folders as a network drive, then copy/paste the files out of the network drive to the new computer. The [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13197/map-a-network-drive-from-xp-to-windows-7/) has an excellent article on how to map a network drive between a Windows 7 and a Windows XP machine.

Mapping a network drive not only gets the information to your new computer, it creates a permanent link between the computers to share the info. Just realize that the network drive is like making a bridge - it doesn't move the data, just let's you access it. But once you access it, you can move it anywhere you like.

Comment: Nice links mate

Comment: I have launched a very similar thread. My concern is sharing files wirelessly between Vista and 8. I am able to send from Vista and display them on Win 8 but the reverse is not happening. Both computers are all sharing settings turned on except the password protected sharing which i turned off. Once i attempt to transfer a file from Win 8 to Vista,  a message appears declaring that i do not have privileges to send the file. Whats the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use filezilla server to ftp locally within my home network.

A free dropbox account is also commonly used to share between computers.

I have found many problems / bugs with trying to use window's networks across different O/S' - not to mention the potential security issues.

Comment: To transfer your entire file system over wifi, I recommend filezilla server.